# Case when for 2 Columns

Tags: sql

Im trying to have my "Case" statements doing 2 different things in 2 separate columns.

As follows: When 'Criteria1' is met, 'Column1' should have "Good". When 'Criteria2' is met, 'Column2' shuold get a 1.

Can anyone help.

```
SELECT [Item_Number],(Sum(Total_Orders)-Sum(On_Hand)) AS Total_Reorder,
    CASE 
         WHEN (Sum(Total_Reorder)-Sum(On_Hand))<0 THEN 0        
         WHEN Sum(Total_Reorder)>0 AND (Sum(Total_Reorder)-Sum(On_Hand))<=0 THEN 'On Hand' END AS OnHand
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: What would happen to column 2 when criteria 1 is met and what would happen to column 1 when criteria 2 is met?

Comment: @PankajGadge im trying to insert the coding, but im not sure exactly how to do it. will try in a few miutes.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai nothing should happen to each other based on the "others" criteria.

Comment: You need two case statements since you are trying to set values for two separate columns.

Comment: @SaravanaKannadasanGandhi so, i was not able to make 2 "cases" with "ends". Is it my problem?

Comment: I think it would be best if you can post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: What type and version of SQL?

Comment: Case _expressions_...

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code sample doesn't reflect the problem you describe, but I would think the following would work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Criteria1 THEN 'Good' END AS Column1,
       CASE WHEN Criteria2 THEN 1 END AS Column2
```

Comment: @MayerFulop no problem. The number of times I've missed a comma in SQL cannot be counted by SQL.

Comment: Now, im encountering another issue, which doesn't have to do with the above. "Couldn't store <> in this Column. exacted type is Int123"

Answer (score 0):

Building on what others have said, here's a complete example for you:

```
create table casetest
( col1 int,
  col2 int
  ) ;


insert into casetest select 2,1 ;
insert into casetest select 2,2 ;
insert into casetest select 2,3 ;


select col1, col2,
    case when col1 = col2 then 'first_condition'
         when col1 < col2 then 'second_condition'
         when col1 > col2 then 'third_condition'
    end as test_01,
    case when col1 = 2 and col2 = 3 then 'extra_condition' else 'nothing' end as test_02
from casetest 
order by col2 ;
```

Comment: let me put it down this way. Im starting with a simple Select Statements - and I want the results to be different if a criteria is met. Than, i want in a seperate column a to tell me if another criteria is met. Am I clear enough?